# how to set column name in DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am taking Excel data into DataTable but it is taking Excel Column name as first row of data in DataTable. So help me to set Excel's first row as columns in DataTable.
PS: I am using Microsoft.Offfice.Interop.Excel and System.Data.DataTable namespace
This is my code:

```
connExcel.Open();
cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmdExcel).Fill(dt);
connExcel.Close();
```

I am getting all the data of specified excel sheet into DataTable dt but it is taking Excel column names as first row of data in Datatable

Comment: Don't use interop. It is gonna cause you much problems in production.

Comment: I have to take excel data into dataTable. suggest me another better way than Interop

Comment: A specialized library, like EPPlus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change a column name, use `ColumnName`.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("A", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("B", typeof(string));

table.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Column A";
table.Columns[1].ColumnName = "Column B";

table.Rows.Add(99, "test row");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable tab = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < tab.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    tab.Columns[i].Caption = "example"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if user altered Excel Sheet before uploading and set  "example" as 3rd Column? Then with above code i will have wrong data in wrong column

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can do the following, it will disable taking the header from the excel workbook:

```
    conn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(
          "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " &
          "data source=" & path & "; " &
          "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1""")
```

Alter the HDR to No in the connection string

Comment: I tried this but it is just adding empty row in DataTable in the first